# CiviCRM Email Record appearing in other members profile Information

Tags: civicrm

We have a Drupal module that allows users to sign up and create their own personal fundraising page. Every Drupal user is matched to their equivalent CiviCRM profile where the information is stored. The Drupal module then reads information from CiviCRM  to display custom reports such as how much they have raised and their contact info.

There is one email that is in the system and is getting overlaid somehow into other members profiles. The owner of the email has not created a page, I'm not sure how their email even got into the system. It has happened twice already. On a mailing the owner of the email account responded saying they were not the correct person.

Any ideas how this happened and how to correct it?

Comment: From the way you are writing, and what I know of 'out of the box' CiviCRM functionality, it sounds like you have a fair amount of custom code going on here.  Can you add some more detail on how you have set this up, links to any custom code, etc. That will help people answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport, and should be posted in appropriate issue queue, not here.

Answer (score 5):

CiviCRM has a table `civicrm_uf_match`, which links CiviCRM contacts to Drupal (or Wordpress or Joomla) users. Here is its structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `civicrm_uf_match` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'System generated ID.',
  `domain_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Which Domain is this match entry for',
  `uf_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'UF ID',
  `uf_name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'UF Name',
  `contact_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'FK to Contact ID',
  `language` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'UI language preferred by the given user/contact',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UI_uf_name_domain_id` (`uf_name`,`domain_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UI_contact_domain_id` (`contact_id`,`domain_id`),
  KEY `FK_civicrm_uf_match_domain_id` (`domain_id`),
  KEY `I_civicrm_uf_match_uf_id` (`uf_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_uf_match_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_uf_match_domain_id` FOREIGN KEY (`domain_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_domain` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4997 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

'UF' stands for Underlying Framework, i.e. the Drupal, Wordpress or Joomla installation to which CiviCRM is linked.

Sometimes entries in this table can get out of sync, e.g. if the Drupal database has been copied from a development server to a test server without also copying the CiviCRM database.

Perhaps that is what has happened in this case. You could check by examining the `civicrm_uf_match` records for the relevant email addresses, which are stored in the `uf_name` field.

It can also be useful to join `civicrm_uf_match` to the Drupal `users` table and check for any records where the email in `civicrm_uf_match` differs from the email in `users`. Also a left join from `civicrm_uf_match` to `users` can highlight orphan `civicrm_uf_match` entries.